# need to parse an html document with custom tags in php

Tags: php, html, parsing

I need a fast way to parse a standard html file with a custom tag like

```
    <xta:exec>text inside</xta:exec>
```

in php, and put this tag "nodeName" and "nodeValue" in an array.

This tag can be anywhere, in a title, in a td element...

I've found this simple way to parse HTML, but parsing give me the (expected) error **"Namespace prefix xta is not defined"**

http://www.expertsguide.info/2010/08/parse-xml-or-html/

Can I define a custom namespace in the example above? There's a better and faster way to do this?

Thanks for the attention!

Gianluca.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SimpleXML, you can use `getNameSpaces`:

```
$namespaces = $node->getNameSpaces(true);
$xta = $node->children($namespaces['xta']);
$exec = $xta->exec;
```